# JQuery - getting all JS functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know of a way to use JQuery for getting JavaScript elements of a web page?
For example, getting all JavaScript function names that are used in page and so on.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *function names that are used in page*? How about anonymous functions which might reside in different scopes?

Comment: Actually I don't mind if it's function names or the entire functions body. So it could be also the anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure if this works but...

```
$("script").remove();
```

doesnt remove only functions but should remove all script elements completely.

**EDIT**

nvm thought i read you wanted to remove the functions

Comment: Try reading the question again. Now read your answer. Any relation?

Answer (score 0):

Getting all the function names is something that jquery should not be needed for--it is more of a language issue.

You can get all of the functions and variables in the global scope by looking at the `window` object, since everything in the global scope in the browser is really a property of this object. However, this will contain *all* of the variables in the global scope, including ones there by default and not added by another script.

You can loop through all of the properties of the `window` object with a `for...in` loop. Here is an example:

```
    for (var obj in window) {
        // obj is just the name of each property
        // do stuff with window[obj]
    }
```

However, if this is not strictly necessary, you should really avoid it. It's possible, but I would think twice before doing this and would be very careful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the code above will not work on IE only chrome and Firefox. Do you have any idea how can I make it to work on IE?

Comment: @Avi, that's an old bug, that unfortunately has no workaround. IE can't enumerate any function declaration (e.g.: `function foo () {}`) made in the global scope, the properties are created in the global object, but `for-in` doesn't visit them. More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/05/04/414684.aspx).